# Restricting a Plugin to Only Load its CSS and JS on Selected Pages?

Tags: plugins, server, performance, css, server-load

I'd like to cause a plugin to restrict its loading of CSS stylesheets and JavaScript JS files to only those pages for which they are needed.

An example for my question is the plugin [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) which I've used to create a form in one page on my site (the "[contact me](http://www.r-statistics.com/contact-me/)" page). However it adds the following lines to EVERY page/post on the website:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://www.r-statistics.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/styles.css?ver=2.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' /> 

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.r-statistics.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/scripts.js?ver=2.3.1'></script>
```

This makes me suspect that this plugin is impairing my site's loading time, for an extension that interests me on only one page on the site.

**Thus, my question is how can I remove these extra lines from all the pages except for the "Contact Me" page but without deactivating the plugin?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Styles and scripts are always set up by the functions `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()`, which have to be tied to a particular action hook in order to function.  I took a peek inside Contact Form 7, and it looks like it's using action tags of `wpcf7_enqueue_scripts` and `wpcf7_enqueue_styles` to add them to the `wp_print_scripts` and `wp_print_styles` hooks.

So, what you need to do is un-hook the scripts and styles from every page *but* your contact page.  The `wp_head` action fires before the script and styles actions, so you'll need to add something like this to your theme's functions.php file:

```
function remove_wpcf7_extras() {
    remove_action('wp_print_scripts', 'wpcf7_enqueue_scripts');
    remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'wpcf7_enqueue_styles');
}

if( ! is_page('contact me') ) {
    add_action('wp_head', 'remove_wpcf7_extras');
}
```

The [is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page) function will return `true` when you're on the contact page (assuming the name is "contact me") ... you can also use the page slug and page ID for the filter.  On all other pages, the `if()` conditional will add the script/style removal function to the `wp_head` action, which fires just before the `wp_print_scripts` and `wp_print_styles` actions.

This should remove the extra code from your pages, and you won't have to deactivate the plug-in or edit any core files.  The functions and code I've listed above also won't cause your theme to break if you remove Contact Form 7 in the future, either ... so no need to worry about future upgrade compatibility.

Comment: Hello EAMann.  Great solution - thank you!  Do you think this method could be enveloped into a plugin that checks which hooks are  used, and then allows someone to deactivate them according to page location?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a lot of hooks that are used dynamically within WordPress.  So you can't reliably detect which hooks are being used ... but you could probably catch most of them this way.

Comment: Cool. you just gave me an idea for a new question:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/698/where-can-i-propose-a-new-plugin

Comment: Just so you know, you've also given me the idea to start developing this plug-in :-)

Comment: That was my hope :)  Any way for me to know once you've got it working ?

Comment: @EAMann and @Tal Galili - Actually you can capture all the hooks, even the dynamic ones using the `all` hook, see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307/

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - Fantastic!  You should really put this in the repository for reference ... we were at a loss when discussing this on the WP-Hackers list last month when looking for an all-hooks solution ... @Tal Galili - I'll post it on my WP site at http://www.jumping-duck.com/wordpress/ if/when it gets done.

Comment: @EAMann - You are the second who suggested that I do so. Okay, I'll put on my todo list (which has a bunch of client work at the head of the list so it may not be immediately...)

Comment: there's a good article and discussion in the comments on this at http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/08/06/how-to-disable-scripts-and-styles