# Force CSS and JS loading of plugin only where needed

Tags: plugins

I saw the excellent answer (link below) but would like to learn for myself how to look for action call of a specific plugin so i can stop it using the idea of EAMan
[Restricting a Plugin to Only Load its CSS and JS on Selected Pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/695/restricting-a-plugin-to-only-load-its-css-and-js-on-selected-pages)

I have used http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/datapress/ and its js/css is only needed on one page.

Same for other plugins. How do I go about finding out what function those plugins call so I can enabled it on only pages needed.

Comment: If the plugin is still actively developed, report your problem back to the plugin author as well please.

Comment: Yes, I did let the author know about it.

Answer (score 2):

is_admin() is useful for the front end.

The load-$pagenow hook and a few others are useful on the backend. wp-admin/admin-header.php, for instance, contains:

```
do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', $hook_suffix);
do_action("admin_print_styles-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_print_styles');
do_action("admin_print_scripts-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_print_scripts');
do_action("admin_head-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_head');
```

Note the $hook_suffix variable, which you can var_dump() then and there to know what its value is when your plugin's page is being loaded.