# Why does this fail: Disabling plugins enqueue_script() in functions.php

Tags: plugin-development, functions, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to use the method presented here:

[Restricting a Plugin to Only Load its CSS and JS on Selected Pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/695/restricting-a-plugin-to-only-load-its-css-and-js-on-selected-pages)

In the plugin 'syntax-highlighter-compress' I've got the following code:

```
function wp_shc_head_scripts() {    
    wp_register_script( 'shCore',       plugins_url('syntax-highlighter-compress/scripts/shCore.js') );
    wp_register_script( 'shAutoloader', plugins_url('syntax-highlighter-compress/scripts/shAutoloader.js') );
    wp_enqueue_script('shCore');
    wp_enqueue_script('shAutoloader');
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'wp_shc_head_scripts');
```

And in functions.php I have:

```
function remove_shc() {
    remove_action('wp_print_scripts', 'wp_shc_head_scripts');
}

if ( is_single( array( 17, 19, 1, 11 ) ) ) {
    add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'remove_shc');
}
```

I've tried various priorites after each add/remove and have tried various hooks (wp_head, shutdown, init) but I can't seem to get this to work!

(Whilst testing, I have the is_single() condition commented out so that the plugin should never load, but it always does.)

What am I missing?  Thanks, Tim

(In future, I'll prob use get a post_meta value to trigger plugin activation, ideally, the plugin should set this on use.. but first things first, eh?)

Comment: You forgot the 'if' in your conditional - assuming that's just a typo.

Comment: yup - typo - i've abbreviated the code for the example - cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. Conditional tags (`is_single()`) should not be used so early in `functions.php`.
2. Your removal function is getting hooked to run after function it's meant to remove.

It should be something like this:

```
function remove_shc() {

    if ( is_single( array( 17, 19, 1, 11 ) ) )
        remove_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wp_shc_head_scripts' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_shc' );
```

Comment: great!  Your code solved the posted issue.. but i haven't quite understood why.. the other hook used is
`add_action('wp_footer','wp_shc_footer');`
and I don't understand at which point I should remove this action.. (I tried removing it at wp_enqueue_scripts and it didn't seem to work)

Comment: @ptim that depends on when is it added, you can't remove something before it is there