# Load js/css files only on specific admin UI pages

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-script, wp-register-style

How do I adapt this [solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/695/restricting-a-plugin-to-only-load-its-css-and-js-on-selected-pages) to work with my plugin? (Please see the link).

I enqueue my css and js script as follows:

```
function my_plugin_init() {
 wp_enqueue_script('my_plugin_script', plugins_url('js/the_filepath.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
 wp_enqueue_style( 'my_plugin_css', plugins_url( '/css/the_filepath.css', __FILE__ ) );
}

add_action('init', 'my_plugin_init');
```

I tried putting this in the theme's functions.php, but it didn't work:

```
function remove_my_plugin_extras() {
    remove_action('init', 'my_plugin_init');
}

if( !is_page('My_Page') ) {
    add_action('wp_head', 'remove_my_plugin_extras');
}
```

The script and css still loaded. How do I adapt the solution in this case?

Answer (score 14):

### The right hooks

```
    // Use both for scripts & styles *)
    wp_enqueue_scripts // (for the frontend)
    login_enqueue_scripts // (for the login screen)
    admin_enqueue_scripts // (for the admin dashboard)
```

<sup>*) Read [this article @wpdevel](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/).</sup>

Further reading in the Codex about the three hooks

- [admin_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu)
- [network_admin_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/network_admin_menu)
- [user_admin_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_admin_menu)

On the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook, you have an argument as well: The `$hook_suffix`:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function( $hook )
{
    var_dump( $hook );
} );
```

### Admin page hooks

When registering [a admin (sub)menu page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus#Example), you can save the result, which is the page hook, into a variable:

```
function register_admin_page()
{
    // Register (sub)menu page
    $hook_suffix = add_submenu_page( $your_args_array );
    // Add styles to hook
    add_action( "load-{$hook_suffix}", 'callback_function' );
}
// Use one of those hooks to register the page
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_admin_page' );
add_action( 'user_admin_menu', 'register_admin_page' );
add_action( 'network_admin_menu', 'register_admin_page' );

// Register your styles & scripts in here
function callback_function()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

### Admin globally available variables to check against

The following

```
global $hook_suffix, $typenow, $pagenow, $self, $parent_file, $submenu_file
```

are available on a wide range of admin pages. Use them to check if you're on the requested page that you need and *only then* do stuff.

```
// Example
if ( 'edit.php' !== $GLOBALS['pagenow'] )
    return;
```

Even better than testing against a variable, which can get reset on the fly (example) ...

```
$GLOBALS['wp'] = array( 'lost', 'my', 'contents', );
```

... is using the `\WP_Screen` object on admin pages:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function( $hook )
{
    /** @var \WP_Screen $screen */
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    var_dump( $screen );
    if ( 'post.php' !== $screen->base )
        return;
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style($hook) {
        // $hook is string value given add_menu_page function.
        if($hook != 'toplevel_page_mypluginname') {
                return;
        }
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', plugins_url('admin-style.css', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```