# Enqueue script in specific page

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, dashboard

I am building a wordpress theme with a theme dashboard with options, but as I read somewhere, the enqueue script code I am using just enqueues it in the backend but it loads in every page in the backend. So I am having some js conflicts...

I have this code:

```
add_menu_page($themename, $themename, 'administrator', basename(__FILE__), 'ikos_admin');
add_submenu_page(basename(__FILE__), $themename . ' Options', 'Theme Options', 'administrator',  basename(__FILE__),'ikos_admin'); // Default
}


function ikos_add_init() {

    $file_dir=get_bloginfo('template_directory');
    wp_enqueue_style("ikosCss", $file_dir."/functions/theme-options.css", false, "1.0", "all");
    wp_enqueue_script("ikosScript", $file_dir."/functions/theme-options.js");
    wp_enqueue_script("ikospickerScript", $file_dir."/functions/color-picker.js", array( 'farbtastic', 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'farbtastic' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'farbtastic' );
    wp_register_script('my-upload', $file_dir."/functions/upload.js");
    wp_enqueue_script('my-upload');

        if(function_exists( 'wp_enqueue_media' )){
        wp_enqueue_media();
}else{
        wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
        wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
        wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
      }

}
```

So, how do I enqueue those scripts in that specific admin page only???
Thanks :D

**EDIT**
YEAH NOW IT IS WORKING!
New code using the hook, then I added the var_dump( $hook_suffix ); exactly before the abort/return statement as @kaiser told me in the comments and it printed this: **string(0) "" string(27) "toplevel_page_theme-options" **.

So I just added the "toplevel_page_theme-options" in the ikos_add_init($hook_suffix) and it works!

```
$hook_suffix = add_menu_page($themename, $themename, 'administrator', basename(__FILE__), 'ikos_admin');
add_submenu_page(basename(__FILE__), $themename . ' Options', 'Theme Options', 'administrator',  basename(__FILE__),'ikos_admin'); // Default

}


add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'ikos_add_init' );

function ikos_add_init($hook_suffix) {
    if ( 'toplevel_page_theme-options' !== $hook_suffix )
    return;
    $file_dir=get_template_directory_uri();
    wp_enqueue_style("ikosCss", $file_dir."/functions/theme-options.css", false, "1.0", "all");
    wp_enqueue_script("ikosScript", $file_dir."/functions/theme-options.js");
    wp_enqueue_script("ikospickerScript", $file_dir."/functions/color-picker.js", array( 'farbtastic', 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'farbtastic' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'farbtastic' );
    wp_register_script('my-upload', $file_dir."/functions/upload.js");
    wp_enqueue_script('my-upload');

        if(function_exists( 'wp_enqueue_media' )){
            wp_enqueue_media();
}else{
        wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
        wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
        wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
      }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside `admin-header.php`, there's the following set of hooks:

```
do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', $hook_suffix);
do_action("admin_print_styles-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_print_styles');
do_action("admin_print_scripts-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_print_scripts');
do_action("admin_head-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_head');
```

The one to ***always*** use it `admin_enqueue_scripts`, both for stylesheet ***and*** scripts. [More info in this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39993/load-js-css-files-only-on-specific-admin-ui-pages).

It has one additional argument, the `$hook_suffix`. This argument is ***exactly*** the same as the return value that you get from [`add_submenu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) and the related (shorthand) functions.

#### Example

*Note:* The following example assumes that you already registered the script previously, so it's available with the handle/identifier of `your_handle`.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse113509_register_script' );
function wpse113509_register_script( $hook_suffix )
{
    if ( 'dashboard.php' !== $hook_suffix )
        return;

    wp_enqueue_script( 'your_handle' );
}
```

#### Additional Notes

As I see that you're identifying the Themes root directory using `get_option('template_directory')`, I have to leave a short additional note as this isn't how it's done nowadays, as this info then comes from the DB, which want to avoid. It as well will ignore the default filters that are in place for that:

- `get_template_directory()` - *Path* to the parent theme root dir
- `get_stylesheet_directory()` - *Path* to the child theme root dir
- `get_template_directory_uri()` - *URL* to the parent theme root dir
- `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` - *URL* to the child theme root dir
- [`plugin_dir_path( __FILE___ )`](http://queryposts.com/function/plugin_dir_path/) - Root of the current file, no matter if in child/parent theme or a plugin. Trailing slashed result.

Then there's `wp_get_theme()`, which calls an instance of `WP_Theme` for the currently active theme.

```
$current_theme = wp_get_theme();
$current_theme->get_theme_root();
$current_theme->get_template();
$current_theme->get_template_directory();
```

If you got a child theme, you can as well simply call `$current_theme->parent()` to access all the other `WP_Theme` methods on the parent themes instance. For e.g.

```
$current_theme->parent()->get_theme_root();
```

This then also allows to access header information from the theme. For e.g. the `Name`, `DomainPath`, etc.

Comment: Can you explain it further please? I am really not getting this :/ Do I need to register all my scripts/css first and then enqueue them? also, the hook_suffix works automatically or do I have to register it or something..? I mean..can you read my code above and explain a little using a piece of it?

Comment: I see your edit and thank you so much for pointing that out! I am new at building themes and all I've done is based on tutorials here and there. I will look into my code and improve those callings of the template directory.

Comment: @CynthiaLara If that helped you solving the problem, then please mark it as solution. Thanks. Oh and about the `hook_suffix` argument: Every argument _after_ the name of a filter or hook inside `do_action()/apply_filters()` is a argument that is available inside the callback.

Comment: I am sorry @kaiser I will mark it as solution when I understand how it works, I am trying to solve the issue using the logic stated there, I would vote up but can't because of my reputation... hold a little and if this works I will happily state your answer as solution :)

Comment: @CynthiaLara Of course. I added above comment exactly for that reason: Helping you to wrap your head around it fast as possible. You might as well want to read my Codex example about [`do_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) for the basics.

Comment: I edited the question with my new code, trying to figure out whats wrong or how to achieve but I am lost :/

Comment: @CynthiaLara Why do you hook the callback that registers the script to `'load-'.$hook_suffix` and not to `admin_enqueue_scripts`, like I've shown in my answer? Btw, please don't post _flat_ code. Use tabs or 4 spaces to keep your code readable. Also, as I've shown in my answer, you _should ***not***_ use `get_bloginfo()` to determine the root. Please stick to the advice. If you ignore it, any help is worth nothing.

Comment: I tried another way of doing this because I couldn't make it work in admin_enqueue_scripts88... about the get_bloginfo() I was going to change it at the end, because well..it was somthing tiny compared to the whole issue... well, I changed it to get_template_directory_uri() now and trying to make the other part work.......

Comment: @CynthiaLara Again, please reformat your question and intent the MarkUp. Non readable as it is. Then please specify what exactly "didn't work" meant (Errors, debugging info, etc.). Last, please always protocol what you tried with edits.

Comment: New code in my edit, and better formatting...as it is said on my edit, this code stops from loading my scripts, I know there is something I am doing wrong but I am kind of lost. Thanks for the patience and help here.

Comment: @CynthiaLara Do a `var_dump( $hook_suffix );` exactly before the abort/return statement. Then browse to the page you want the have scripts loaded on. Then add exactly this output to your abort statement so it can prevent from loading elsewhere. Then update your question to reflect your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the URL of the page you want to enqueue the js into.  It might be sth like

```
/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=cpt&page=thisfile.php
```

Then just use that like

```
if($_GET['page'] == 'thisfile.php' AND is_admin())
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
```

Comment: Almost there (I guess)...now for example, the media upload won't work correctly in other admin pages. I tried to set a featured image but it won't load the media library as always in a fancybox, it sends me to a new page with the old uploader and no thumbs. Help please :(