# load styles and scripts in network admin not working

Tags: multisite, admin-menu

I am trying to load scripts on three different screens ONLY. I am getting the styles on the `ins-carrier-display` pages but they do not print on the `ins-carrier-edit` page.

Am I missing something?

```
// Create admin page navigation listings
function bf_carrier_admin_network() {
  global $bfc_admin_page;
  $bfc_admin_page = add_submenu_page('settings.php', 'Carriers', 'BrightFire Carriers', 'edit_posts', 'ins-carrier-edit', 'carrier_admin_network');   
}

function bf_carrier_admin_actions() {
  global $bfc_admin_page;
  if (current_user_can('manage_options')){
    $bfc_admin_page = add_options_page('BrightFire Carriers', 'BrightFire Carriers', 'edit_posts', 'ins-carrier-display', 'carrier_admin');   
  }else{
    $bfc_admin_page = add_menu_page('Carriers', 'Carriers', 'edit_posts', 'ins-carrier-display', 'carrier_admin','dashicons-products',58);
  }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'bf_carrier_admin_actions');
add_action('network_admin_menu', 'bf_carrier_admin_network');

//registser admin scripts
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'bfc_styles_scripts');
function bfc_styles_scripts(){
  global $bfc_admin_page;

  $bfc_admin_screen = get_current_screen();

  if ( $bfc_admin_page == $bfc_admin_screen->id ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-drop');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-highlight');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bfc_admin_style', plugins_url( 'css/admin.css' , __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', plugins_url('js/bootstrap.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.3.2'); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of research on here and it seems I was trying too hard. I have found the following solution. Props to this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39993/load-js-css-files-only-on-specific-admin-ui-pages/40006#40006).

```
// Create admin page navigation listings
function bf_carrier_admin_network() {
  $hook_suffix = add_submenu_page('settings.php', 'Carriers', 'BrightFire Carriers', 'edit_posts', 'ins-carrier-edit', 'carrier_admin_network');    

  add_action( "load-{$hook_suffix}", 'bfc_styles_scripts' );
}
add_action('network_admin_menu', 'bf_carrier_admin_network');

function bf_carrier_admin_display() {
  if (current_user_can('manage_options')){
    $hook_suffix =  add_options_page('BrightFire Carriers', 'BrightFire Carriers', 'edit_posts', 'ins-carrier-display', 'carrier_admin');   
  }else{
    $hook_suffix = add_menu_page('Carriers', 'Carriers', 'edit_posts', 'ins-carrier-display', 'carrier_admin','dashicons-products',58);
  }

  add_action( "load-{$hook_suffix}", 'bfc_styles_scripts' );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'bf_carrier_admin_display');

//register admin scripts
function bfc_styles_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-core');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-drop');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-highlight');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bfc_admin_style', plugins_url( 'css/admin.css' , __FILE__ ));
  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', plugins_url('js/bootstrap.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.3.2'); 
}
```