# JQuery UI plugin not working in IE7?

Tags: plugins, jquery, jquery-ui, browser-compatibility, compatibility

I want to use the dialog box from [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-ui-widgets/), but it isn't compatible for IE7. When I run it in Internet Explorer's IE7 emulator, the dialog box renders weirdly. It's partly transparent, draggable/resizable doesn't work, and the title disappears.

As far as I know, the problem seems related to one (or both) of these:

1. The console says IE7 doesn't support "querySelectorAll". Is there a workaround for this?
2. If I render the page in Quirks document mode, everything works fine. Is there a way to force IE7 to render pages in Quirks mode? I've come across [this](http://www.charliecochran.com/blog/index.php/how-to-force-quirks-mode-in-ie7-but-keep-to-standards-mode-in-ie8-and-other-browsers/), which suggests adding a comment before the doctype -- but I don't know how to do that in WordPress.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IIRC IE7 is not supported even by microsoft. Slim chance anyone will bother answering this kind of question on any site.

Answer (score 2):

Bad news first: We can't fix your JS problem (at least as long as the errors come from the jQuery UI version shipped with core and not from your custom definitions). This is a WordPress core problem. When you look at the [SVN trunk](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/jquery-ui-widgets/trunk/), especially [the main (and only) PHP file](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/jquery-ui-widgets/trunk/jquery-ui-widgets.php) in that folder, you will see that the plugin doesn't even ship with *any* script... at least this is what I thought first. Then I found that it *does* register a script.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquiw_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Point is, that I couldn't find a script by searching for `js` (the file extension), because the plugin does the following:

```
function jquiw_initialize_scripts() {

        $options = get_option( 'jquiw_options' );

        /* If jQuery code text box not empty then add to header. */
        if ( ! empty( $options['txtar_jquery_code'] ) ) {
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n";
                echo $options['txtar_jquery_code'] . "\r\n";
                echo "</script>\r\n";
        }

        /* If custom CSS text box not empty then add to header. */
        if ( ! empty( $options['txtar_override_css'] ) ) {
                echo "<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n";
                echo $options['txtar_override_css'];
                echo "\r\n</style>\r\n";
        }
}
```

As you can see, the JavaScript and the style definitions come from `get_option( 'jquiw_options' )`. And when we look at the rest of the plugin file, then we see that there is actually a `<textarea name="jquiw_options[txtar_jquery_code]">` where *you* did enter the JavaScript. Not that it's completely bad to save something like *executable* JavaScript into a DB, the really **bad** thing is when you don't sanitize it:

```
function jquiw_init() {
        /* Make sure we always have a theme selected. */
        $tmp = get_option( 'jquiw_options' );
        if ( ! isset( $tmp['drp_jquery_theme'] ) ) {
                $tmp["drp_jquery_theme"] = 'smoothness';
                update_option( 'jquiw_options', $tmp );
        }
        register_setting( 'jquiw_plugin_options', 'jquiw_options' );
}
```

As you can see, there is nothing what holds anyone back from saving malicious code. In short: Drop that plugin, register the jQuery UI stuff you need yourself and write your own `.js` files that contain the definitions for the scripts.

Use the Dependencies API yourself - A [quick guide/"How-To" for registering scripts and styles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39993/load-js-css-files-only-on-specific-admin-ui-pages/40006#40006).

You can fetch the CSS via the Google CDN.

```
$theme = 'smoothness';
"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/{$theme}/jquery-ui.css"
```

then simply add jQuery UI:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
```

on top of that, you just enqueue the plugins you want and add `jquery-ui-core` as dependency to get the right loading order:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-accordion', null, array( 'jquery-ui-core', ) );
```

Finally you register your definitions from within a custom file. There you avoid using all the stuff that the browsers you support don't like.

Make sure to **wrap that up in a custom plugin** of your own.

Comment: Can you explain why the problem described in the question is a "WordPress core problem" as you said? I don't see it. I see a js pure problem, no WordPress specific and generated by a third party plugin.

Comment: @cybmeta Because jQuery UI with its widgets ships with core. Extended in an edit.

Comment: I see now; anyway the request in the question is how to add support for "querySelectorAll" in IE 7 or how to force page rendering in quirks mode.

Comment: @cybmeta That may be a _solution_, not necessarily the answer. There's always a high chance that a question actually faces a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).