# Unable to apply selective loading

Tags: wp-head

I wanted to get rid of unnecessary calls in my header. I would like a plugin 'wizylike' to load only on 'posts', nowhere else ( archives, pages etc.). I have taken a hint from [this thread on how to load plugin selectively](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/695/restricting-a-plugin-to-only-load-its-css-and-js-on-selected-pages?rq=1) and worked out a little code that goes to functions.php.

```
function remove_wizy() {
        remove_action('init', 'wizylike_init');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wizylike_head');
        remove_action('wp_print_scripts', 'wizylike');
        remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'wizylike');
}

if( !is_single() ) {
        add_action('wp_head', 'remove_wizy');
    }
```

**Problem** : Plugin is still printing the scripts across all the pages in the header. Either I am not able to identify the right handle or am executing it wrong. I have tried many variations and failed so I thought will ask here now. Here is the code of the plugin's loader.php.

```
// constants paths
define('WL_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));

// constants URIs
define('WL_URI', get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-content/plugins/wizylike');
define('WL_CSSURI', WL_URI . '/css');
define('WL_JSURI', WL_URI . '/js');
define('WL_IMGURI', WL_URI . '/images');


// Calls database global
global $wpdb, $wl_tablename;


// Combines default db tables prefix with our newly tabel name
$wl_tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'wizylike';


// includes plugin files
require_once(WL_PATH . '/widget.wizylike.php');         // Sidebar widget


// Runs when the plugin is activated
function wizylike_activate() {
    global $wpdb, $wl_tablename;

    if (!empty($wpdb->charset))
        $charset_collate = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET $wpdb->charset";

        // run the SQL statement on the database
        $wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE {$wl_tablename} (
                            id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                            post_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
                            ip_address VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
                            user_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
                            like_status VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'like',
                            PRIMARY KEY (id), 
                            UNIQUE (id)
                            ){$charset_collate};");

        $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE `$wpdb->posts` ADD `like_count` BIGINT( 20 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0'");

    update_option('wizylike_capabilities', 'users-only');
    update_option('wizylike_colour', 'red');
    update_option('wizylike_style', 'style_1');
    update_option('wizylike_like_txt', 'Like?');
    update_option('wizylike_unlike_txt', 'Unlike!');
    update_option('wizylike_widget_txt', 'Likes');


}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wizylike_activate');


// Runs when the plugin is deactivated
function wizylike_deactivate() {
    global $wpdb, $wl_tablename;

    $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE `$wpdb->posts` DROP `like_count`;");
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$wl_tablename};");
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'wizylike_deactivate');


// register functions
add_action('admin_menu', 'wizylike_settingspage_create');
add_action('init', 'wizylike_init');
add_action('admin_init', 'wizylike_admin_init');


// settings page create
function wizylike_settingspage_create(){

    if (isset($_POST['wizylike_save'])) {
        // $wizylike_settings['wizylike_capabilities'] = $_POST['wizylike_capabilities'];
        $wizylike_settings['wizylike_unlike_txt'] = $_POST['wizylike_unlike_txt'];
        $wizylike_settings['wizylike_like_txt'] = $_POST['wizylike_like_txt'];
        $wizylike_settings['wizylike_colour'] = $_POST['wizylike_colour'];
        $wizylike_settings['wizylike_style'] = $_POST['wizylike_style'];
        $wizylike_settings['wizylike_widget_txt'] = $_POST['wizylike_widget_txt'];

        foreach($wizylike_settings as $name => $val) {
            if(isset($_POST[$name])) {
                update_option($name, $val);
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST['wizylike_capabilities'])) {
            update_option('wizylike_capabilities', 'users-only');
        } else {
            update_option('wizylike_capabilities', 'all');
        }

        header("Location: options-general.php?page=wizylike&saved=true");
        die;
    }

    $page = add_options_page( __('WizyLike', 'wizylike'), __('WizyLike', 'wizylike'), 'manage_options', 'wizylike', 'wizylike_settingspage');
    add_action('admin_head-' . $page, 'wizylike_adminhead');    
}


// wizylike front-end init

function wizylike_init(){

    // includes main class
    require_once(WL_PATH . '/class.wizylike.php');

    // includes template tags for ease of usage
    require_once(WL_PATH . '/template-tags.php');

    // adds necessary stylesheets to wp_head
    wp_enqueue_style('wizylike', WL_CSSURI . '/wizylike.css', false, '1.0', 'screen');

    // adds necessary javascripts to wp_head
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('wizylike', WL_JSURI . '/wizylike.js', false, '1.0', false);
}


// wizylike back-end init
function wizylike_admin_init(){
    // adds necessary stylesheets to wp_head
    wp_enqueue_style('wizylike-admin', WL_CSSURI . '/admin.css', false, '1.0', 'screen');

    // adds necessary javascripts to wp_head
    wp_enqueue_script('wizylike-admin', WL_JSURI . '/admin.js', false, '1.0', false);
}


// wizylike back-end head
function wizylike_adminhead(){

}


// wizylike front-end head
function wizylike_head(){
    $js = '<script type="text/javascript"> var wizylike_url = "' . WL_URI . '"; </script>' . "\n";
    echo apply_filters('wizylike_head', $js);

    do_action('wizylike_head');
}

add_action('wp_head', 'wizylike_head');

// wizylike settings page callback
function wizylike_settingspage(){
    require_once(WL_PATH . '/wrap.php');
}
```

Comment: `wp_head` runs after `init`. Have you tried `add_action( 'init', 'remove_wizy', 5 );` instead of `add_action('wp_head', 'remove_wizy');`

Comment: Yes I did. It entirely disables the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It dequeues the style and script set in `'init'`.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'remove_wizzylike' );

function remove_wizzylike() {
    if ( ! is_single() )
        add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_wizy', 5 );
}

function remove_wizy() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wizylike_head' );

    // Enqueued in wizylike_init()
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wizylike' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wizylike' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying @charles. Unfortunately the plugin is still disabled on single page. Script do not load on 'pages' anymore but looking at view-source the script do not load on single posts either.

Comment: You are probably checking `is_single()` too early. It is not usable until after the query has been run. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, the last edit works. There was a small typo for 'add-action' instead of 'add_action' though. I am still trying to realize what I did wrong. Thank you @charles, Really appreciated.