# How can I force a file download in the WordPress backend?

Tags: plugins

I would like to add a "Click to download" button to one of my WordPress plugins, and I'm not sure which hook to use. So far, hooking 'admin_init' to this code seems to work:

```
 header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");
 echo 'data';
 exit();
```

This seems to work, but I just want to see if there is a best practice out there.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to have **a URL something like the following** whose response to the browser will be the content you generate, i.e. your `.CSV` file and no generated content from WordPress?

```
http://example.com/download/data.csv
```

I think you are looking for the `'template_redirect'` hook. You can find `'template_redirect'` in `/wp-includes/template-loader.php` which is a file all WordPress developers should become familiar with; it's short and sweet and routes every non-admin page load so be sure to take a look at it.

Just add the following to your theme's `functions.php` file or in another file that you `include` in `functions.php`:

```
add_action('template_redirect','yoursite_template_redirect');
function yoursite_template_redirect() {
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/downloads/data.csv') {
    header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload",true,200);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    echo 'data';
    exit();
  }
}
```

Note the test for the `'/downloads/data.csv'` URL by inspecting `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Also note the added `,true,200` to your `header()` call where you set the `Content-type`; this is because WordPress will have set the `404` *"Not Found"* status code because it doesn't recognize the URL. It's no problem though as the `true` tells `header()` to replace the `404` WordPress had set and to use the HTTP `200` *"Okay"* status code instead.

And here's what it looks like in FireFox *(**Note** the screenshot doesn't have a `/downloads/` virtual directory because after taking and annotating the screenshot it just seemed like a good idea to add a `'/downloads/'` virtual directory):*

[image: Screenshot of a download URL for a CSV file]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101101-064407.png))</sub>

### UPDATE

If you want the download to be handled from a URL that is prefixed with `/wp-admin/` to give the user the visual indication that it is protected by a login you can do that as well; the description of one way follows.

I encapsulated into a class this time, called `DownloadCSV`, and to created a user *"capability"* called `'download_csv'` for the `'administrator'` role *(read about Roles and Capabilities [**here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities))*  You could just piggyback off of the predefined `'export'` role if you like and if so just search & replace `'download_csv'` with `'export'` and remove the `register_activation_hook()` call and the `activate()` function. By the way, the need for a activation hook is one reason why I moved this to a plugin instead of keeping in the theme's `functions.php` file.*

I also added a *"Download CSV"* menu option off the *"Tools"* menu using `add_submenu_page()` and linked it to the `'download_csv'` capability.

Lastly I chose the `'plugins_loaded'` hook because it was the earliest appropriate hook I could use. You could use `'admin_init'` but that hook is run much later (1130th hook call vs. the 3rd hook call) so why let WordPress do more throw-away work than it needs to? *(I used my [Instrument Hooks plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-wordpress-hooks/339#339) to figure out which hook to use.)*

In the hook I check to ensure my URL starts with `/wp-admin/tools.php` by inspecting the `$pagenow` variable, I verify that `current_user_can('download_csv')` and if that passes then I test `$_GET['download']` to see if it contains `data.csv`; if yes we run practically the same code as before. I also remove the `,true,200` from the call to `header()` in the previous example because here WordPress knows it is a good URL so didn't set the 404 status yet. So here is your code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Download CSV
Author: Mike Schinkel
Author URI: http://mikeschinkel.com
 */
if (!class_exists('DownloadCSV')) {
  class DownloadCSV {
    static function on_load() {
      add_action('plugins_loaded',array(__CLASS__,'plugins_loaded'));
      add_action('admin_menu',array(__CLASS__,'admin_menu'));
      register_activation_hook(__FILE__,array(__CLASS__,'activate'));
    }
    static function activate() {
      $role = get_role('administrator');
      $role->add_cap('download_csv');
    }
    static function admin_menu() {
      add_submenu_page('tools.php',    // Parent Menu
        'Download CSV',                // Page Title
        'Download CSV',                // Menu Option Label
        'download_csv',                // Capability
        'tools.php?download=data.csv');// Option URL relative to /wp-admin/
    }
    static function plugins_loaded() {
      global $pagenow;
      if ($pagenow=='tools.php' && 
          current_user_can('download_csv') && 
          isset($_GET['download'])  && 
          $_GET['download']=='data.csv') {
        header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        echo 'data';
        exit();
      }
    }
  }
  DownloadCSV::on_load();
}
```

And here's a screenshot of the activated plugin:
[image: Screenshot of Plugin Page showing an activated plugin]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101104-061049.png))</sub>

And finally here's a screenshot of triggering the download:
[image: Screenshot of Downloading a file by URL from an option of the WordPress admin's Tools menu]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101104-062726.png))</sub>

Comment: Mike, thanks for your help. The only catch with this feature is that I would like the file to be downloaded from the backend. It looks like template_redirect doesn't work on the backend, and if I'm not supposed to use admin_init, I wonder what I should use instead. admin_init seems to work for me now, I might stick with it at least for the short term. It's a minor feature that only a few people are going to use.

Comment: @Dave Morris - Can you define what you mean by *"back end"*? Do you mean on the server? If yes, `'template_redirect'` most definitely runs on the server. If not, I'd totally confused; can you clarify the concern? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dave: If you mean the admin area by the "back end", this will still work. The download URL starts with `/downloads/data.csv`, which is a non-existing file, so the WordPress "front end" will handle this request and eventually reach `template-redirect`. You just create a link in the admin area that points to this frontside URL. (It must be said that this way, you don't get the admin login protection for free - anyone who knows the URL can download the file, but maybe there is an easy way to fix that?)

Comment: @Jan Fabry - Ah, I understand now. By *"back end"* he meant from within the admin, right? He can use the function `current_user_can()` with the above code or take another approach. After this comment I'll add an update to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I apologize, I am not receiving email alerts from this site, so that explains my delay in answering back. I was indeed referring to the admin area of WordPress when I said "backend". Sorry about that. I will try using template_redirect and see what happens. Thanks! ~Dave

Comment: @Dave Morris - `template_redirect` is more for external access. Try the second example I posted.

Comment: This is excellent. You saved me a lot of trouble. I just want to clarify to others who might not need the submenu page that all you need to do is hook the `DownloadCSV` class method `admin_menu` to the action hook with the call to `add_action('admin_menu',array(__CLASS__,'admin_menu'));` and add your code to force the download in the method code.

Comment: If you want to use `WP_Query` to get data to create your downloadable file, use `'admin_init'` hook instead of `'plugins_loaded'`. If not, you'll get "Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object_id()".

Answer (score 4):

one more useful plugin for exporting into CSV. may be useful to some one

```
<?php

class CSVExport
{
    /**
    * Constructor
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['download_report']))
        {
            $csv = $this->generate_csv();

            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Cache-Control: private", false);
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"report.csv\";" );
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

            echo $csv;
            exit;
        }

        // Add extra menu items for admins
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'admin_menu'));

        // Create end-points
        add_filter('query_vars', array($this, 'query_vars'));
        add_action('parse_request', array($this, 'parse_request'));
    }

    /**
    * Add extra menu items for admins
    */
    public function admin_menu()
    {
        add_menu_page('Download Report', 'Download Report', 'manage_options', 'download_report', array($this, 'download_report'));
    }

    /**
    * Allow for custom query variables
    */
    public function query_vars($query_vars)
    {
        $query_vars[] = 'download_report';
        return $query_vars;
    }

    /**
    * Parse the request
    */
    public function parse_request(&$wp)
    {
        if(array_key_exists('download_report', $wp->query_vars))
        {
            $this->download_report();
            exit;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Download report
    */
    public function download_report()
    {
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
        echo '<div id="icon-tools" class="icon32">
        </div>';
        echo '<h2>Download Report</h2>';
        //$url = site_url();

        echo '<p>Export the Users';
    }

    /**
    * Converting data to CSV
    */
    public function generate_csv()
    {
    $csv_output = '';
    $table = 'users';

    $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."");

    $i = 0;
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $csv_output = $csv_output . $row['Field'].",";
            $i++;
        }
    }
    $csv_output .= "\n";

    $values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table."");
    while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
        for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
            $csv_output .= $rowr[$j].",";
        }
        $csv_output .= "\n";
    }

    return $csv_output;
    }
}

// Instantiate a singleton of this plugin
$csvExport = new CSVExport();
```

Answer (score 3):

**admin_init** Hook or **load-(page)** Hook seems to work, WordPress has not been set header in this state.
I'm using **load-(page)** Hook because it runs when an administration menu page is loaded.
You can load your script for specific page.

You can check [load-(page) Hook on WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-(page))

If you're using **admin_init** Hook make sure to **verify nonce** using **check_admin_referer** or other script maybe pass the condition will get output your download file.