# How to find hooks as per Just-In-Time approach?

Tags: hooks, actions

How can I follow `Just-In-Time` approach in hooking up my function to an action? I mean everybody just attach the functions to a very early stage like `init` which leaves the scope of optimisation. I saw in a Wordcamp presentation once that JIT will yield some performance and I totally agree with it but how do I find out what's the last hook I can hook to?

Anything which can help in understanding the WP code execution flow too?

Comment: Is this curiosity, or do you have a specific problem you are trying to solve? I ask because you make a vague statement about performance. In my experience, trying to "improve performance" just on general grounds tends to be a waste of time.

Comment: Learning it once will enable me to produce better code. Gain might not be always worth it but with time, I am sure it won't take more than a few seconds more to figure out whats the best hook to attach a function.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Mike's answer to a similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-wordpress-hooks/339#339)
more specifically the plugin he posted there can be used to create a list of all action hooks and filters that were called to generate that page in order of execution.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the time, people use the `init` hook. But this can be a mistake for many cases of conditional execution. For example, at `init` time, the view type ('home', 'single', 'page', 'archive', etc) is not yet known. If you need to conditionally call your function based on `is_page()` or similar, you need to use a hook that executes later, like `template_redirect`.

Similarly, for admin-side events, it is usually better to use the `admin_menu` hook rather than `admin_init`.

The resources in the Q/A pointed to by @Bainternet are very useful, so you should definitely look at those. But I thought I'd just point out a couple of specific things that might be useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

I myself use something different, but got this snippet to advance my hook "spoofer" one day.

```
function list_hooks( $filter = false ){
    global $wp_filter;

    $hooks = $wp_filter;
    ksort( $hooks );

    foreach( $hooks as $tag => $hook )
        if ( false === $filter || false !== strpos( $tag, $filter ) )
            dump_hook($tag, $hook);
}

function list_live_hooks( $hook = false ) {
    if ( false === $hook )
        $hook = 'all';

    add_action( $hook, 'list_hook_details', -1 );
}

function list_hook_details( $input = NULL ) {
    global $wp_filter;

    $tag = current_filter();
    if( isset( $wp_filter[$tag] ) )
        dump_hook( $tag, $wp_filter[$tag] );

    return $input;
}

function dump_hook( $tag, $hook ) {
    ksort($hook);

    echo "<pre>&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;\t<strong>$tag</strong><br />";

    foreach( $hook as $priority => $functions ) {

    echo $priority;

    foreach( $functions as $function )
        if( $function['function'] != 'list_hook_details' ) {

        echo "\t";

        if( is_string( $function['function'] ) )
            echo $function['function'];

        elseif( is_string( $function['function'][0] ) )
             echo $function['function'][0] . ' -> ' . $function['function'][1];

        elseif( is_object( $function['function'][0] ) )
            echo "(object) " . get_class( $function['function'][0] ) . ' -> ' . $function['function'][1];

        else
            print_r($function);

        echo ' (' . $function['accepted_args'] . ') <br />';
        }
    }

    echo '</pre>';
}
```

*If someone wrote this, pls name yourself as the author (with a link to orig. source). I forgot to safe the link.*

---

*Edit:* You should also take a look into this page [@Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). There you can see the order in which order get triggered.
Should give you a start: `/root/index.php > wp-blog-header.php > wp-load.php > wp-config.php > wp-settings.php > \wp-includes\load.php > \wp-includes\default-constants.php > ...` best would be you grab some debug class from somewhere and just check the includes local.