# How to know what functions are hooked to an action/filter?

Tags: hooks, actions, filters

Is there a way to know what functions are hooked to a particular hook? For example if I'd like to know what functions are hooked to the `wp_head` hook.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this does what you want: [@Rarst's Debug WordPress hooks](http://www.rarst.net/script/debug-wordpress-hooks/)

Comment: take a look at [**this answer**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-wordpress-hooks/339#339) to a similar question and more specifically the plugin posted there by mike.

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't that just produce a comprehensive list of hooks? The way I'm reading the question is the he wants to know what functions are attached to the hook.

Comment: Partially wrong, he said "for example what's hooked to wp_head", so its a full list not only a single hook.

Comment: Indeed, I wanted to see what functions are attached to a particular hook, so for example if 10 functions are hooked to `wp_head` then I'd like to list those 10.

Comment: well that plugin will list all functions that are hooked with there hook.

Comment: just stumbled across this plugin which is pretty great for this https://wordpress.org/plugins/simply-show-hooks/

Comment: To contribute - in this matter, its not so very friendly to use the collected hooks information, and specially not on 'wp_head'. The closest correct way (explained) is the snippet:

    function list_hooks($hook = '') ...

found at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26680808/2445357

That works as of 2018 and been awsome for this kind of solutions. You will found hooks from plugins, classes and nestled object and count them all! Or easy list where the functions resident etc etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look into the global variable `$wp_filter`. See my [plugin for a list of all comment filters](https://gist.github.com/867302) for an example:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: List Comment Filters
Description: List all comment filters on wp_footer
Version:     1.1
Author:      Fuxia Scholz
License:     GPL v2
*/

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'list_comment_filters' );

function list_comment_filters()
{
    global $wp_filter;

    $comment_filters = array ();
    $h1  = '<h1>Current Comment Filters</h1>';
    $out = '';
    $toc = '<ul>';

    foreach ( $wp_filter as $key => $val )
    {
        if ( FALSE !== strpos( $key, 'comment' ) )
        {
            $comment_filters[$key][] = var_export( $val, TRUE );
        }
    }

    foreach ( $comment_filters as $name => $arr_vals )
    {
        $out .= "<h2 id=$name>$name</h2><pre>" . implode( "\n\n", $arr_vals ) . '</pre>';
        $toc .= "<li><a href='#$name'>$name</a></li>";
    }

    print "$h1$toc</ul>$out";
}
```

Sample output for `pre_comment_author_email`:

```
array (
  10 => 
  array (
    'trim' => 
    array (
      'function' => 'trim',
      'accepted_args' => 1,
    ),
    'sanitize_email' => 
    array (
      'function' => 'sanitize_email',
      'accepted_args' => 1,
    ),
    'wp_filter_kses' => 
    array (
      'function' => 'wp_filter_kses',
      'accepted_args' => 1,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 23):

to see list of functions or actions hooked to a particular action hook you can use the following code.

```
global $wp_filter;
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $wp_filter['wp_head'] );
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 5):

For debug-purposes a simple

```
global $wp_filter;
echo "<pre>" . print_r($wp_filter, true) . "</pre>";
```

would do it ...

Comment: In my case, calling `var_dump($wp_filter)` produced too much output. I preferred using `var_dump($wp_filter["<action name>"])`. (Same goes for `print_r` - I personally preferred var_dump.)

Answer (score 5):

This shows a more readable list of filters

```
function print_filters_for( $hook = '' ) {
    global $wp_filter;
    if( empty( $hook ) || !isset( $wp_filter[$hook] ) ) return;

    $ret='';
    foreach($wp_filter[$hook] as $priority => $realhook){
        foreach($realhook as $hook_k => $hook_v){
            $hook_echo=(is_array($hook_v['function'])?get_class($hook_v['function'][0]).':'.$hook_v['function'][1]:$hook_v['function']);
            $ret.=  "\n$priority $hook_echo";
        }

    }
     return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from @Simone G useful, but it didn't take into account the fact, that sometimes Closures can be hooked. Here's my more verbose (and ugly) version:

```
if( isset($wp_filter[$filterName]) ){
    foreach( $wp_filter[$filterName] as $priority => $hooks){
        foreach ($hooks as $hook_k => $hook_v) {
            $hook_echo=(is_array($hook_v['function'])?get_class($hook_v['function'][0]).':'.$hook_v['function'][1]:$hook_v['function']);
            if(is_object($hook_echo) && ($hook_echo instanceof Closure)){
                $hook_echo="closure";
            }
            error_log($filterName." HOOKED (".serialize($priority)."): ".serialize($hook_k)."".serialize($hook_echo));
        }
    }
} else {
    error_log($filterName." NO FILTERS HOOKED");
}
```