# wp_enqueue_scripts not called on search page?

Tags: theme-development, customization, hooks, search, debug

I've written a custom theme. It's pretty complex so I won't post a huge code block here for everyone's sanity.

In my `functions.php` file I have the following hook being called:

```
function DA_script_enqueue() {
    if( is_404() ){ 
        //load scripts with wp_enqueue_script() 
    }
    if( is_search() ){ 
        //load scripts with wp_enqueue_script() 
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'DA_script_enqueue');
```

What happens on my wordpress website when my theme is activated is that no scripts get added to the `search.php` page but they **do** get added to the `404.php` page which is very odd! In fact, not even killing the page works with `die();`

```
if( is_search() ){ 
   die('it works');
}
```

This leads me to think that the condition is never being met within the hook override for `wp_enqueue_scripts`. I'm not sure if this is a bug, or if my logic is just incorrect and I'm calling the wrong functions. What else can I try to make my logic work?

Thanks

**Edit:**
Okay an update: I just tried the above code in another theme and it **DOES** do what it's supposed to! I guess the question I should now be asking is what can I do to ensure `is_search()` returns `true`? So far I've disabled **all** plugins and removed a `query_posts()` call from index.php, but still facing issues :(

**Edit #2:**
After 9 hours of debugging this (*sigh*) I've finally found what's causing the problem (but no solution to it - yet!)

I created a test wordpress site and copied over my custom theme files. I deleted them one by one until I had the bare minimum files needed for a theme and that's when I found out what was causing the problem. It seems having a `header.php` file makes `is_search()` return `false`. Very strange!

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the screenshots above, as soon as I delete the header.php file everything is fine as `is_search()` returns true.

What on earth could be causing this very strange issue? I have other themes with a header.php file in them and they work fine...

I'm going to continue to play around with this but here are my source files just in case:

`search.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

search page

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

`functions.php`:

```
<?php
        // This function will load certain scripts on certain pages - saving on bandwidth and server resourses.
    function init_scripts()
    {
        if ( is_search() ) {
            die('Yes this is the search page loading from the init_scripts function');
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'init_scripts' );
?>
```

`header.php`:

```
header
```

**Edit #3:**
Here is the output of `$wp_query` also http://pastebin.com/Z0DwDd20

**Edit #4:**
Time for bed now so I guess I'll have another shot at this tomorrow. Here's the theme files just in case anyone is interested: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1zYR-LjR-j9NFV2ZXg3V0NJblk&usp=sharing

Comment: Are you using `query_posts` somewhere on your search page. It is the most probable cause why `is_search()` would return false on the search page

Comment: Hi @PieterGoosen thanks for your reply. That's an interesting catch. I've just tried deleting all contents of my `search.php` file but the `die('it works');` still doesn't get executed. Any other ideas?

Comment: You don't exactly tell us how is your theme/search built but do you need to enqueue and use your script only in search results or search page overall? From [codex:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) _Some themes include a search.php template file. This **is not** a Search Page, it is merely a template that displays the search results._. Why not to use `is_page_template()` instead of `is_search()`?

Comment: Something is breaking the main query on your search page. Do `var_dump( $wp_query );` on your searh page and inspects the query object. It should tell you what is going on

Comment: @N00b Yes, search page overall. I've tried removing all conditional statements from my `DA_script_enqueue` function and now I know for sure that the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook *isn't* firing on my `search.php` page. The `die()` works on *ALL* pages of my site except for the search page. I tried adding `is_page_template()` but kept getting false returned. My last test was to do a general check in `functions.php`. I did `if ( ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) { }` and now `search.php` *is* being detected but no jquery is being added. This is sooo weird! Any other suggestions?

Comment: Okay an update. I just tried my code from the OP in another theme and it DOES do what it's supposed to! I guess the question I should now be asking is what can I do to ensure `is_search()` is returning true? So far I've disabled all plugins and removed a `query_posts()` query from `index.php` but still nothing :(

Comment: @JoelMurphy in a search, right under `wp_head()` in your `header.php` file grab print the WP_Query as Pieter suggested and put it here ( or in a pastebin ) - `global $wp_query; print_r( $wp_query ); die();` This may bring some insight.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just did this. Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/Z0DwDd20

Comment: @PieterGoosen See anything wrong with this? It looks like a traditional search query - nothing here sticks out to me as odd. `is_search()` should be able to catch on that this is a search page. You've said it works on a default theme but you have gone through disabling all plugins? Maybe reinstalling WordPress?

Comment: Yeah it works on another theme I have so I'm out of ideas. Time for bed now so I guess I'll have another shot at it tomorrow. Here's the theme files just in case anyone is interested: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1zYR-LjR-j9NFV2ZXg3V0NJblk&usp=sharing

Comment: @Howdy_McGee everything is quite normal from the dump/print, which 99.9% confirms the use of `query_posts` somewhere in the OP's theme or in a plugin the OP is using.

Answer (score 2):

When using `wp_enqueue_script`, you probably passing `true` for `in_footer` parameter. If so, then check that your `search.php` is calling `get_footer()` function at the bottom.

Comment: very important comment!

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer to your question, I can explain your confusion over deleting the header file. The `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook is fired in the `wp_head()`, which must be in your `header.php` file. Your dummy header file doesn't include this, so the entire `DA_script_enqueue` function isn't running at all. When you delete the header.php file, WordPress uses a default instead, which does include `wp_head`.

For your original problem you'll need to go back to square one and debug things a bit at a time, but without losing the `wp_head()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The `var_dump` from the main query is fine, `is_search()` returns true as it should. Also, the SQL query look fine for a search page.

This further deepens my suspicion that something is altering the main query right after it is successfully executed, and this happens most probably before `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

The most probable culprit here is `query_posts`. I can remember a while ago that someone had such an issue which turned out to be YOAST plugin (*IIRC*) which used `query_posts` or some bad filter or something, and the issue was solved by deactivating the plugin.

Your best place to start here would be to search your theme for `query_posts` and sort that out if there is any instances of `query_posts`. If it is not in a theme, you'll need to look into your plugins. Deactivate your plugins one by one and test after each one has being deactivated. You should be able to find the culprit with this method

### EDIT

Try resetting the main query on `wp_enqueue_scripts` and then check if your styles and scripts are enqueued from your action. If so, that means that `is_search()` returns true, which 99.9% confirms the use of `query_posts` somewhere in your theme or plugin.

***NOTE:*** This is just a test and **not** a solution.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function ()
{
    wp_reset_query();
}, 9 );
```

### EDIT 2

I just realised that you have already deactivated all plugins. As you have stated, when you delete `header.php`, your results is ok.

**Debugging**

Unfortunately, the files you linked to does not help as it is basicly just all the themes in you themes folder, but here is some basic debug info

- Code editors has quite good search functions which you can use to search for spefific strings inside all files within your theme. I would start by searching for all instances of `query_posts`, specially inside your functions files as it seems like the issue is caused by something hooked to an action hook which resides in the header or is actually hooked to `wp_head`
- `header.php` houses the `wp_head()` function which is just a wrapper for the `wp_head` action. There are many action hooks (*like `wp_enqueue_scripts`*) hooked to `wp_head`. Check [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/17394/31545) in order to get a list of everything hooked to `wp_head`. As a quick debugging check to check if the issue is caused by anything hooked to `wp_head` before going on a wild goose chase, simply delete `wp_head()` and check the `is_search()` condition. Obviously, if `is_search()` return true then, something hooked to `wp_head` is causing the issue.
- `header.php` also houses functions like navigations menus, and most of these functions are filterable to filters. It might be that there is a bad filter that is used by one of these functions. If the above two bullet points where fruitless, delete these functions one by one to determine the bad apple. nce you have the bad apple, it is as easy as looking at the source code to determine which filters it uses and then looking for these custom filters in your theme's function files