# Help to create function that changes name in the certificate of the sensei lms

Tags: plugins

I would like to remove the concatenation of the first and last name of the student certificates through the "Sensei LMS Certificates" plug-in. I would like to show only the first name, make an edit in the files
* class-woothemes-sensei-certificate.php * and in * class-woothemes-sensei-certificate-tempates *, the file comes with the concatenation like this:

```
// Get Student Data
            $user_id      = get_post_meta( $certificate_id, 'learner_id', true );
            $student      = get_userdata( $user_id );
            $student_name = $student->display_name;
            $fname        = $student->first_name;
            $lname        = $student->last_name;

            if ( '' != $fname && '' != $lname ) {
                $student_name = $fname . ' ' . $lname;
            }
```

and I changed it to:

```
// Get Student Data
        $user_id      = get_post_meta( $certificate_id, 'learner_id', true );
        $student      = get_userdata( $user_id );
        $student_name = $student->display_name;
        $fname        = $student->first_name;
        $lname        = $student->last_name;

        if ( '' != $fname && '' != $lname ) {
            $student_name = $fname;
        }
```

However, if there is an update to the plug-in, I will lose those settings. I would like to include a function in functions so that certificates are kept only the first name. Could someone help me create this function for my child theme's functions.php file?
How can I insert a function in the file that changes this?

Comment: As Sensei is part of the WooCommerce environment, it may well have the possibility to override template files by recreating them in your theme.  I also took a peek at the Sensei Certificate documentation and it allows you to create your own certificate templates.  Not sure if that's the specific plugin you're using though: https://senseilms.com/documentation/sensei-certificates/

Comment: Hi Tony

Yes or plugin that is used (https://github.com/woocommerce/sensei-certificates) however, I can change only the certificate templates, but the files that start with the class cannot be recovered in the children's theme, configuration that I need to change the main plugin file and miss the update. You need to change the $ student_name variable that is concatenating the first name and the last name, and I would like it to be considered only the first name.

Comment: So the certificate template builder doesn’t allow you to specify just the first name?  That seems like a poor decision on the developers part.  You should suggest a change on the plugin’s support pages, I imagine quite a few users would like that idea.

Comment: Additionally, you could, when editing the template, remove the segment that draws the name from the class and instead query the user’s data instead and only place the first name.  I’d have to see how the template looks, but if it’s adding the output of the class in your question, we’d simple edit that out of the template and then add our own method for extract the info we want.

Comment: Okay, my model file has an output

$ woothemes_sensei_certificate_templates-> generate_pdf ();

file link: https://github.com/woocommerce/sensei-certificates/blob/master/templates/single-certificate_template.php

then I see the use of the function in the class files folder
https://github.com/woocommerce/sensei-certificates/blob/master/classes/class-woothemes-sensei-certificates.php
and
https://github.com/woocommerce/sensei-certificates/blob/master/classes/class-woothemes-sensei-certificate-templates.php

Comment: Ok, looking through those links, I realized that this leads to the generation of a PDF, so there isn't an HTML template file we can add to our own theme.  That means my suggestion is, basically, rubbish.  Sorry.  I didn't realize it was a PDF generation utility.

Comment: I think the only approach you'd be able to take would be to remove the actions from the certificate plugin from your own plugin, and then add them back in but with your changes.  It's a tricky process, but it can be done: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223652/remove-action-from-plugin-on-other-plugin