# Too many revision when post status is changes

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, revisions

When ever i update the custom post type it generates too many revision which crashed the website.  ( memory exceeded)
How can i debug this issue?

[image]

Update : 
I was able to find the culprit. Will it be possible for some one to detect what i did wrong in the below code :

```
if (class_exists('wpprolister_core')) {

    add_action('wp_insert_post', 'wpprolister_updated_to_publish', 10, 3);

    function wpprolister_updated_to_publish($post_id, $post, $update)
    {

        if (get_field('wpprolister_advanced_option_edit_seo', $post_id)) {

            $metatitle     = get_field('wpprolister_seo_title', $post_id);
            $metadesc      = get_field('wpprolister_seo_meta_description', $post_id);
            $metakeywords  = get_field('wpprolister_seo_keyword', $post_id);
            $content       = get_field('wpprolister_description', $post_id);
            $image         = get_field('wpprolister_listing_slider_image', $post_id);
            $attachment_id = $image['ID'];

            if (!empty($image)):
                $size  = 'medium';
                $thumb = $image['sizes'][$size];
                if (defined('WPSEO_VERSION')) {
                    update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', $metatitle);
                    update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', $metadesc);
                    update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', $metakeywords);}
                //also update the content and featured image
                $my_post = array(
                    'ID'           => $post_id,
                    'post_content' => $content,
                );
                wp_update_post($my_post);
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id);

            endif;

        }
    }
}
```

How i solved the problem (please let me know if i did wrong ):

```
remove_action('wp_insert_post', 'wpprolister_updated_to_publish');
            $my_post = array(
                'ID'           => $post_id,
                'post_content' => $content,
            );
            wp_update_post($my_post);
            add_action('wp_insert_post', 'wpprolister_updated_to_publish');
```

Comment: Why are you changing the post status so frequently? Maybe there's an alternative to that, without these symptoms? One can also control how many revisions to keep, I guess you've looked into that?

Comment: @birgire i not changing the post status , some thing is triggering it..i am not able to find that ,i tried removing revisions but didn't worked out

Comment: @Charles , actually there there is no problem with that ..i was able to find out that some thing is going wrong with `wp_update_post($my_post);`in the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try looking which functions are hooked to the `save_post` action and then see what those functions are doing. Perhaps there's some kind of an infinite loop in one of them. Try looking into the global variable `$wp_filter`, more on that here, [How to know what functions are hooked to an action/filter?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17394/how-to-know-what-functions-are-hooked-to-an-action-filter)

Comment: Hi, thanks ..it helps a lot..a little confused on using that..will it be possible how it is used for save_post? ..i am able to view the page without any issue but unable to change the status , like to draft, to publish etc

Comment: thanks i was able to find out what was causing the issue , the code above causes the troubles.