# Can the wp_filter object hold multiple values with the same key

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I'm trying to understand the internals of the `$wp_filter` object and I'm looking at the code posted by Fuxia in this question [How to know what functions are hooked to an action/filter?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17394/how-to-know-what-functions-are-hooked-to-an-action-filter)

```
function list_comment_filters()
{
    global $wp_filter;

    $comment_filters = array ();
    $h1  = '<h1>Current Comment Filters</h1>';
    $out = '';
    $toc = '<ul>';

    foreach ( $wp_filter as $key => $val )
    {
        if ( FALSE !== strpos( $key, 'comment' ) )
        {
            $comment_filters[$key][] = var_export( $val, TRUE );
        }
    }

    foreach ( $comment_filters as $name => $arr_vals )
    {
        $out .= "<h2 id=$name>$name</h2><pre>" . implode( "\n\n", $arr_vals ) . '</pre>';
        $toc .= "<li><a href='#$name'>$name</a></li>";
    }

    print "$h1$toc</ul>$out";
}
```

As far as I can tell the code in the first `foreach` loop, and the call to `implode` in the second `foreach` handle a case where the `$wp_filter` object contains two entries with same key. So my questions are

- Is this possible?
- Under what circumstances would this occur?

**Edit**

Following the answer from Jacob Peattie I can see that `$wp_filter['save_post']` could hold multiple values, to phrase my question in another way, in this section of the code

```
foreach ( $wp_filter as $key => $val )
    {
        if ( FALSE !== strpos( $key, 'comment' ) )
        {
            $comment_filters[$key][] = var_export( $val, TRUE );
        }
    }
```

is there ever a scenario when the same `$key` value could be encountered twice? I suspect that

```
$comment_filters[$key][] = var_export( $val, TRUE );
```

could be changed to

```
$comment_filters[$key] = var_export( $val, TRUE );
```

and the results the function returns would always be the same.

Or is there a scenario where `$wp_filter` could contain two elements with the same key (not one element that holds an array/WP_Hook with references to multiple functions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, keep in mind that the structure of `$wp_filter` was changed in WordPress 4.7: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/09/08/wp_hook-next-generation-actions-and-filters/

As for your questions:

> Is this possible?

Yes.

> Under what circumstances would this occur?

If multiple functions have been hooked to the same action/filter, eg:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'do_a_thing' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'do_another_thing' );
```

In that case `$wp_filter['save_post']` will have multiple values.

---

To address your edit:

> is there ever a scenario when the same $key value could be encountered twice? I suspect that
>
> ```
> $comment_filters[$key][] = var_export( $val, TRUE );
> ```
>
> could be changed to
>
> ```
> $comment_filters[$key] = var_export( $val, TRUE );
> ```

No, it's not possible for the same *key* to be encountered twice. PHP arrays cannot have the same key more than once.

Your amended code is correct. In fact, without that change `implode( "\n\n", $arr_vals )` will probably not produce the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so based on that link, if I'm running the code on a version of WordPress > 4.7  `$wp_filter['save_post']` will be an instance of WP_Hook and will not have multiple values. But for previous WordPress versions it would be an array with multiple values. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but WP_Hook implements the ArrayAccess and Iterator, so in practice there’s not much difference.

Comment: Thanks again , so after WordPress 4.7 the `wp_filter` object no longer contains multiple entries with the same key, it will contain a single entry of type WP_Hook, that can be iterated over to find the linked functions. Is that right?

Comment: I've checked a WordPress version prior to 4.7 and I can see how `$wp_filter['save_post']` is an array instead of a WP_Hook object but all the data is still held in a single place rather than across multiple places in the `$wp_filter` object that share the same key.    I've updated my question as I'm not sure if it was clear what I was asking in the first edit.

Comment: I've updated my answer.