# Modify request query string before plugins

Tags: plugin-development

I have an issue where a plugin allows some behavior I don't like. Basically, I want to grab and modify a request query string before the Ultimate Member plugin processes it. Basically if someone isn't a super admin, and the query parameter

```
URI?&..&..&um_action=action_to_take&..
```

is requested anywhere, I want it to force that query string to say edit, so Ultimate Member always responds like the request was this:

```
URI?&..&..&um_action=edit&..
```

Here's the idea, but I'm not sure what hooks/filters/what I'd need to do to trick Ultimate Member:

```
function called_before_ultimate_member () {
    // if not a super admin, don't let this query string 
    // get parsed by Ultimate Member as anything but "edit"
    if (!is_super_admin())
    {
        if (isset($_GET['um_action'])) $_GET['um_action'] = "edit";
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? The plugin is huge, and I don't really have the time or patience to modify core files at this point.

Comment: Do you know what the plugin is hooked to?  @MikeSchinkel's answer here will show you what's in use and where.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/339/45202

Comment: It looks like just 'init'. Would I want to modify the vars just *after* init, after Ultimate Member calls its add_query_args commands?