# How to know what filter to use and how to use it?

Tags: filters, hooks

How can I know what filter I can use to change anything and what my function have to return ?

For exemple, sometimes I have to add a  or a  to a post title. It works (WP doesn't sanitize html tag here) but it's not readable when list the posts in admin because titles are always displayed as is, not HTML sanitize.

So, I want to filter html tag on title but only when I list them in admin (not in front and not when I edit a post).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know WordPress hooks and their uses. for list of hooks please find [Where can I find a list of WordPress hooks?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-wordpress-hooks)

Comment: It's not what I want : of course I already have this but I don't want to guess what filter I have to use. There are over 2000 hooks : having a list don't help me. I already use different plugin to track their calls. But I want to know WHEN they are called. [Simply Show Hooks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simply-show-hooks/) plugin is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a cautious approach in your hooked functions and test whether you are on the front end or admin of the site.

You could search the latest WP source for the hook you are using and see where it will have an impact.